# PHP read in every 10 out of 100 lines

Tags: php, text-files, nested-loops

I'm trying to read in a text file of 5000 lines. However I only want to get the first 10 lines of every 100 lines. So line 1-10, line 101 - 110, line 200 - 210 etc. I just cant figure out the logic to use.

```
$count = count(file($text))

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
 {
 $test = fgets($f_text)
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `% 100` and only print lines where `$n % 100 > 0 && $n % 100 <= 10`.

```
$lines = file($text);
foreach ($lines as $n => $line) {
  if ($n % 100 > 0 && $n % 100 <= 10) {
     echo $line; // or whatever
  }
}
```

#### A sample of how the logic works:

```
foreach (range(0,250) as $n => $line) {
  if ($n % 100 >= 1 && $n % 100 <= 10 ) {
    echo $i . "\n";
  }
}

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your code works a dream, Im just trying to understand the logic behind it.If $n is equal to 11, then wouldnt 11 % 100 be 1? then echo 11?

Comment: % is mod operator. It returns the remainder. So 11/100 is 0 with a remainder of 11. Not 1.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of it the other way around. Your help has been much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with an [`SPLFileObject`](http://php.net/splfileobject), as long as you know how many lines are in the file:

```
$file = new SplFileObject( $filename, "r");

$lines = 0;
while ( !$file->eof()) {
   $file->fgets();
   $lines++;
}
```

Now you know there are `$lines` number of lines in the file. If that is static, say 5000, just initialize `$lines` to 5000. If it's not, let's round that down to the nearest 100:

```
$lines -= ($lines % 100);
```

Now, we just loop over every hundred, seek to the grouping of 10, and grab the data we want:

```
$data = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < $lines; $i += 100) {
    $file->seek( $i);
    for( $j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
        $data[] = $file->fgets();
    }
}
```

With this solution, you never load the whole file into memory, which will save resources when dealing with large files. Also, if you know the size of the file beforehand, you will only read the lines of data that you require.

Comment: Why bother reading like that? Just put the logic in the loop to begin with.

Comment: This never reads the whole file into memory, and only loads the data into memory that is going to be operated on.

Comment: I know, but since you're looping to count the lines to begin with, why not read them there too? It's a waste to do it twice.

Comment: You could, I separated the logic in case the OP wanted to declare `$lines` as a static value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on both other answers, probably the most memory-efficient way to do it:

```
foreach(new SplFileObject($filename) as $n => $line)
    if($n % 100 < 10)
        echo $line;
```

Comment: Can you explain whats occuring. I dont understand ($n % 100 < 10) as by my way of thinking 11 % 100 would = 1?

Comment: @user1544223: No. 11 modulo 100 is 11.

Comment: It may be because it late at night and my brain is fried but does modulus not give you the remainder? So would the answer not be 1. Your right the answer is 11 but I'm just trying to understand. I Again I feel stupid asking this.

Comment: @user1544223: The remainder of 11 divided by 100 is 11. 11 < 100. Are you thinking of 11 modulo 10?

Comment: Ahh ok. sorry your right I was looking at it the other way round. Thanks for clarifying that for me and thank you for your time.