# Getting lines out of a long text

Tags: php

Ok, I got a digital book of 30.000 lines. I want to show only the first 20 lines of a chapter as a preview, every chapter got 300 lines.

Anyone an idea how to solve this? I tried the following:

```
foreach ($lines as $n => $line) {
  if ($n >= 0 && $n =< 20) {
     echo $line;
  }
```

This will result in showing the first 20 lines of the first chapter. So how do I repeat this for all the other lines?

show 0-20
show 300-320
show 600-620
show 900-920
etc..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your PHP max_execution_time: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: @sємsєм Who said anything about a timeout issue?

Comment: @Stijn It is just kind of prediction, when looping through 30K lines you must consider it.

Comment: @sємsєм looping through 30k lines was the first mistake.

Comment: So @MathewFoscarini how would you've done the job?

Comment: I'd store the preview as a separate thing from the book. Why bake a view for a preview every time someone wants to view it? Do it once and cache the results.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Very logical and excellent solution. However, let we say that solutions regarded below, should be used to perform what you considered, because 30K/300 = 100, then manually entering 100 * 20 lines is time consumed and may be automated well, using one valid solution below.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini, actually I'm doing that. This script is only to get the content and store the preview. Got over 60 books to get content from so I had to create a script for storing previews, was searching for a solution to get some content out of every 300 lines. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer myself on an earlier SO question:

```
foreach ($lines as $n => $line) {
     if ($n % 300 > 0 && $n % 100 <= 20) {
         echo $line; // or whatever
     }
 }
```

Based on the answer written by Michael Berkowski ([PHP read in every 10 out of 100 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713937/php-read-in-every-10-out-of-100-lines))

Comment: And look at your memory settings in config ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with:

```
$rgChapters = [];
$rFile      = fopen('/path/to/file', 'r');
$iLines     = 20;
$iChapter   = 300;
$i          = 0;
while($sData = fgets($rFile) && !feof($rFile))
{
   if($i % $iChapter < $iLines)
   {
      $rgChapters[floor($i/$iChapter)].=$sData.PHP_EOL;
   }
   $i++;
}
fclose($rFile);
```

-as a result, you'll get an array with first 20 lines every 300 lines (or you can directly output data rather than store it in array)

Comment: seems like overkill. `$lines = explode("\n",file_get_contents(...));`

Comment: @MathewFoscarini yeah... I'll see what will happen if those 30.000 rows are 10Mb for each row :p (and as for `explode` + `file_get_contents` - a great option will be `file` then)

Comment: true, but we don't know about the reading part. The OP is trying to render a view, and reading should be done elsewhere. could be from a database?

Comment: Well, he has an array. But as for source - you're correct - it could be anything. In fact, he's using `foreach` - which means that he stores entire data within script and so size is not a matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To print chapter 5

```php
$chapter = 5;
$pages = 20;
$start = $chapter*$pages;
for($i=$start, $c=$start+$pages-1; $i < $c; $i++)
{
    echo $lines[$i];
}
```